# Svg Buttons Vs Nine Patch Buttons

Tags: android, svg

Has anybody experience with using svg for creating custom buttons on android? I recently stumbled upon the [svg-android project](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/) that was used for androidify and I'm wondering whether it is worth the trouble rewriting the code.

At the moment I'm using nine-patch buttons. The only problem is that I need to create several images for different resolutions. However, if I switch to vector graphics, I'm not sure how to  preserve the rounded corner radius when I resize the button, for example.

Has anyone experience and can tell me whether it's worth the trouble ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should maybe use Shapes instead of 9-patches. They superior in most of the cases (especially with rounded corners, gradients ...) : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

You can also use layer-lists to stack shapes.

Comment: that looks really nice. However, a different problem arises. I try to paint two boxes with a height of 50% each. I want them to scale properly but that seems to be impossible.

Comment: Create the Boxes in your Layout with Views. It should be possible to give them 50% height there. Then apply the background you created with the shapes.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I used the svg-android project, it wasn't sufficient for my SVG's due to limitations in its rendering. I don't know what its current state (if different) is, but based on my year-old experience with this on Android, I'd say spend some time to experiment with it before you commit to using it -- perhaps its limitations will not affect you.